# tomcat 7 configuration for browser cache memory

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

How to configure tomcat 7 for creating browser cache prevent page? Because i try to disable cache using some response header but it's working partially.

Comment: Do u intend to disable browser cache?then that needs to be set via http header via application

Comment: tnx for your reply,i was tried but not working in mozila firefox. depending upon the  browser we need modify response header,so i plan to configure server.